# Errors with SVN Server runs on Windows Server 2008 R2，can‘t connect to the SVN Server with TortoiseSVN client

Tags: svn, windows-server-2008, visualsvn-server

I just want to install VisualSVN Server 2.5.4 on the server machine runs with Windows Server 2008 R2.That when I install it on my win2003, there without any problem. But just have troubles on the Server2008.

The problem is what I　can't connect to the SVN server with other computer. And when I use the server to connect itself, TortoiseSVN failed to do, just can through the web browser to browser the files in SVN Server. The other hosts can't visit the SVN　URL through the web browser all the same.I have added the SVN Server TCP port 3690 on the Firewall.

Can sb. knows how the trouble occur & how to resovle it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you say "errors with" and "doesn't work" and "fails to do", you need to provide more information. What "errors" do you get? What error messages? What does "doesn't work" mean? Please edit your post to provide more details, and remember we can't see your screen from here; we only have the information you give us in your question to use to try to help you. If you don't tell us what the errors are, it's really hard to help you fix them. :)

Answer (score 1):

VisualSVN Server on install stage asked you, which port to use for connection. If you start Server Manager Console, you can see this port at starting page (and status of server).

[image: Main page]

Action - Properties (Network tab) for root node will allow to change used port, if needed.

[image: Settings]

Event Viewer also collects all records about VisualSVN Server in separate category, where port can be discovered

[image: Event Viewer]

PS - **port 3690 in no way related** to VisualSVN Server functioning - it's port for svn:// based repository, VisualSVN server provides http:// (https://) **only**

Comment: Yeah,ty for tell me so many details,but I found that the trouble isn't related to the firewall either,when I disabled the firewall,it still can't run correctly.&I alse haven't found there's any event recorded in the event viewer.I don't know how the problem comes out.Twe machines with server 2003 can run it well,just the newer OS,but the other people says the VisualSVN Server can be compatible to the 2008 R2 perfectly,I don't know is there anything I configured wrong?Will it affected by the AD?

Comment: @Xuanlove Create at least one repo, define port of server, try to connect with 1) browser 2) cli-client